# Regex to Match US Telephone Numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have some (somewhat) working code to match US-based telephone numbers in the following format: `###-###-####`

The problem is, my code is just hitting the `else` block in my code for each `phone_number` in my `phone_numbers`:

```
file = open("results.txt", "w")
rgxpattern = '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$'
regexp = re.compile(rgxpattern)

for phone_number in phone_numbers:
    phone_number = str(phone_number)
    if regexp.match(phone_number):                      
        file.write('\n')
        file.write(str(phone_number))
    else:
        file.write('BAD#')
```

Is something wrong with my rgxpattern above? I've tried using:

```
^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

and

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

**Example Phone number:**

```
 111-222-3333  
 777-444-4444
```

**Extract of results:**

```
BAD#BAD#BAD#BAD#
```

Any thoughts or help?

Comment: Show an example of the kind of phone numbers that your pattern didn't match, but you want it to.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation) from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) should help you.

Comment: Please show an extract of `results.txt`.

Comment: What is `phone_numbers`?  If it is a list of the lines in the file, then you will need to strip the newline character at the end of each.  Did you do this?

Comment: [Please see this link for a lot of different regex validations for phone numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: @Ben - please see the above extraction

Comment: @p.s.w.g - see the examples above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your "Example Phone numbers" is accurate, then there is white space before and after each phone number, this should remedy the problem:

```
^\s*\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\s*$
```

Comment: Wow, this had me really scratching my head. Great point. This fixed it. Thanks alot :)